# A movie into a movie into a movie

Tags: reference

There are movies with scenes in which a character is watching another actual movie, where by "actual movie" I mean a movie existing in the real world.

For example, in [I Am Legend (2007)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0480249/) the protagonist watches [Shrek (2001)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0126029/) at home. Another example is [A Futile and Stupid Gesture (2018)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5566790/), with the protagonist watching [Airplane! (1980)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080339/) in theater.

I wonder if there is a movie in which a character watches a movie in which a character watches a movie.

Comment: I haven't confirmed it yet, but [Last Action Hero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Action_Hero) seems like a good contender here, as a significant portion of it takes place inside a movie world.

Comment: Recommendation questions asking for movies/TV-shows or resources to locate or watch movie/TV content are off topic

Comment: @Paulie_D Is this also considered recommendation? Isn't this closer to first appearance questions? The OP does not state to want to see a movie or locate it, just to know if there is such a film/are such films, and what the title is/titles are.

Comment: At best it's an overly broad *list* question and those are discouraged for that reason.

Comment: @Paulie_D How is this a "discouraged" "overly broad list question", but this other 69-votes question is not? https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/49204/the-most-roles-played-by-the-same-actor-in-a-movie/49216

Comment: @user38141 To be fair (and I don't actually object to questions like this one) ... the 69-vote question is asking for a specific "who has the most" answer, not a list of matching movies.

Comment: Last Action Hero doesn't count; all fake. Spaceballs doesn't count; all the same movie. ... "another actual movie" watching "another actual movie".... Where *another* is "used to refer to a different person or thing from one already mentioned or known about" *not* "an additional person or thing of the same type as one already mentioned or known about", and *actual* meaning it has an ISAN number.

Comment: @Mazura You are right: I forgot that I wrote "another." So Spaceball doesn't count. I unmarked the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *[Killer Eye: Halloween Haunt](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1998395/)*, also known as *The Disembodied*, the characters watch* the movie *[The Killer Eye](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0177886/)*, which in turn has a character watching *[Creepozoids](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092795/).* All three movies were made by schlock director David DeCouteau.

[image: Characters in The Disembodied, watching The Killer Eye][image: Character in The Killer Eye, watching Creepozoids][image: Creepozoids, being watched by a character in The Killer Eye, being watched by characters in The Disembodied]

The exact sequence takes place at about 24:03 during [Killer Eye: Halloween Haunt, watchable on Tubi.com legally and for free!](https://tubitv.com/movies/460617/the-disembodied)  Although be warned it is quite NSFW, even the scene in question, and that, it um, isn't very good.

*<sub>I use the word "watch" solely in an "in-fiction" way.  At no time are the characters in the same shot of the TV actually showing the movie, although there are shots of the characters staring at what we are assured is the TV, and the characters talk over the *Killer Eye* footage sometimes.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

To some degree, there is an infinite loop in [*Spaceballs* (1987)](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094012/).

Comment: This is a great answer BUT, as Mazura pointed out, I asked for a movie in which a character watched "another actual movie," not the same movie.

Comment: Actually, you didn't.  You just asked for a movie in which a character watches a movie in which a character watches a movie.  You may want to go back and rephrase the question.